# Changing python interpreter in spyder

Tags: macos, python-2.7, spyder

I'm running spyder 2.3.8 on Mac OS 10.11.4. I've installed spyder with the .dmg installer. I would like to use the python 2.7.11 interpreter located in `/opt/local/bin/python` (found with `which python`):

```
~> which python
/opt/local/bin/python   
~> /opt/local/bin/python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Mar  1 2016, 18:40:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
```

So I've changed the interpreter in spyder using Preferences > Console > Advanced settings > Use the following Python interpreter: /opt/local/bin/python. But still, when I launch spyder, it runs python 2.7.10. I don't understand why. Any idea?

Comment: This is indeed unexpected. if you `import sys` and then print `sys.version`, is it still 2.7.10?

Comment: You are right: `In[2]: sys.version
Out[2]: '2.7.11 (default, Mar  1 2016, 18:40:10) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)]'`. But at launch, I have in the iPhyton console: `Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun  1 2015, 09:45:55) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`. I really don't understand.